# Php send form data into specific Mysql database in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

Main issue : Can't insert data into my database from a html form.

I have a WordPress site and I need to store and get data from a specific database. So I have my WP database that WP use, and I have a second database on the same server to store specific data. From this second database, I managed to recover data like that :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "my_user_name";
$password = "my_password";

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><strong>ID</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>Nom d'équipe</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>TOP</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>JUNGLE</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>MID</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>ADC</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>SUPPORT</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>ELO</strong></td>";
echo "</tr>";


if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    global $current_user;
    #print('Hello, ' . esc_html($current_user->display_name) ."<br />\n");

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dbName", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "La connexion à la base de données a échouée. Veuillez réessayer plus tard.";
        }

    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM team WHERE id_owner = $current_user->ID");

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo "<tr>";
        print("<td><i>".$row['id_team']."</i></td>");
        print("<td>".$row['name']."</td>");
        print("<td>".$row['top']."</td>");
        print("<td>".$row['jgl']."</td>");
        print("<td>".$row['mid']."</td>");
        print("<td>".$row['adc']."</td>");
        print("<td>".$row['supp']."</td>");
        print("<td>".$row['elo']."</td>");
echo "</tr>";
    }
}
else {
    print('Vous devez être connecté pour accéder à cette page !');
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

This work perfectly, I get my information depending on the connected user :

[image]

But now, I need to insert data into my database, so I have an HTML form :

```
<form action="inscription.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Nom d'équipe :</label>
    <input id="name" name="user_name" type="text"></div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">Pseudo TOP :</label>
    <input id="mail" name="top" type="text"></div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">Pseudo JUNGLE :</label>
    <input id="mail" name="jgl" type="text"></div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">Pseudo MID :</label>
    <input id="mail" name="mid" type="text"></div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">Pseudo ADC :</label>
    <input id="mail" name="adc" type="text"></div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">Pseudo SUPPORT :</label>
    <input id="mail" name="supp" type="text"></div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Élo moyen de l'équipe :</label>
    <select name="nom" size="1">
      <option>Iron</option>
      <option>Silver</option>
      <option>Gold</option>
      <option>Platinum</option>
      <option>Diamond</option>
      <option>Master</option>
      <option>Grand-Master</option>
      <option>Challenger</option>
    </select></div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="insert">
  <div class="reset"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></div>
</form>
```

And I don't know what to do next. I can't add PHP code here, so I wanted to create a PHP file where I can put a function, but I don't know how to call the function, I don't know where to store my PHP file, how to get HTML data from the form and how I need to write my function... Can someone help me on this part please ? I would be very grateful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your PHP file in the same directory as your HTML file.
Just name it how you want and set the action of the form (yourfilename.php). When you submit this form it will try to call the PHP file. Now you can get the values of the input fields by using $_POST['']. inside the quotes you must place the name of the input field. From here on you can insert the data with INSERT queries.

Is this the answer you are looking for?

this might make it clearer:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_post.asp

Comment: Thank you for your first answer that help me a lot ! 
I think that the aswer I was looking for. Just do you know where the html page are stored ? Cause I read on internet that the content of page was stored in table (database) and the template in wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/ . So where I'm supposed to put my php file exactly ? :/

Comment: Yes, the index should be in your theme folder. In the same folder you can insert a php file.

Comment: Ok that's work correctly ! Thank you very much man, have a nice day.